# Url rewrite without pattern IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have a intranet site in asp.net and IIS 7.5
I want to hide the url pattern like this:

192.168.1.1/a.aspx --> 192.168.1.1/

I want only the http_host, every web page must be hidden. Is it possible with url rewrite module of IIS?

Comment: Still waiting for the solution.

I need Help!